# What is the difference between 'width' and 'padx' in tkinter in python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I just started python tkinter today, and i am not able to differentiate between what the 'width' function does and what 'padx' does, could you please explain each of them to me.

Answer (score 2):

The `padx` is nothing but padding inside the layout, X indicates the x axis. The elements inside the layout tells that it needs more space inside the layout than what is allocated.

`width` which you already know is distance from one side to another side.

Answer (score -1):

It's just like in web development. Let me provide a simple drawing example on `width` vs `padx`

[image]

Example you have two boxes or you can imagine them as widgets now `width` is just the width of your **BOX** or **Widget**. Now for `padx` is just the space `(green stuffs)` within your widget or box you can see the difference from the drawing that I provided.

Comment: Could have used straight lines to show padx rather than random scribbles, also i dont THINK your entirely correct, your width is relative to the box but padx is related to the widget? Width would be the width of the star and padx would be how far the widget moves inside the box on the x axis

Comment: Ohhh... sorry for that... does it make the answer terrible?

Comment: KInd of does, not sure if what i know about padx is wrong either, but i think padx is same as margins in css and ipadx is same as padding in css

Comment: woow can't believe those are a big deal for you. and padx is different from margin, margin is the space `outside` while padding is `within`

Comment: It was a tip to make your answer, look more professional. Hmmm padx and ipadx, i see, maybe im wrong, not sure.